# postgres authentification failled for user

Tags: postgresql, local, postgresql-9.2, identification

I'm having trouble connecting to my local postgres server. so I went to `pgpass.conf`.
In my `pgpass.conf` file the syntax is the following:

host: port: *: database: user. So no value for password but when I connect I have the following error :  error connecting to the server `FATAL: failed password identification for postgres user`

Comment: pgpass.conf has a defined format, you can't just invent your own.  According to that format, the password you are supplying is ' user'. But I doubt that that is what your .pgpass.conf actually looks like, as the white space would also be messing things up, and so you would be getting prompted to enter a password as there would be no match.

Comment: You may try with resetting the password for user "postgres". First change the authentication mode to trust in pg_hba.conf file and restart the DB server. After that connect to database using user postgres, it wont ask password. After successfully login you will be able to set the postgres user password.